# How to add custom category attribute in the layered navigation filters in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

I'm new to Magento 2 and trying to figure out the way to implement the following scenario:

We have categories with custom attribute which is multi-select. These attributes need to be category-specific.

Eg:  `Category : Supplier 1,  Custom attribute : Supplier Type --> Values: Local, Offline` etc.

Now we need to add this filter in the layered navigation filter - side tab on the product listing page with filter values like Local, Offline, etc.

Is there is way to show this category-custom attributes in sidebar filters like product attributes?

Or

To Create some custom attributes in the product page with the value of the same option as of category custom attribute and update values when `category-custom attribute` is updated using some queue job. Is this the right way to do it in `Magento2`

- how we can trigger jobs when category custom attributes are updated?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unrelated but make sure to know that :  For multiselect, the required type is varchar instead of type text otherwise it won't work with filter. And about your question, I don't think thats possible, it might be possible to make a job when the category is updated only i guess. And in that job then you might want to check what is modified to make your modification there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a multi select product attribute with same as category attribute ,,Set the values for that attribute, and update all products with that custom values.
then after --

1. Just go to product attributes on backend.
2. choose your custom attribute
3. Click on `Storefront Properties` , select `Use in Layered Navigation` field as `Filterable (With result)`
   4.Save Attribute , Clear cache ,Then test it.

Comment: It is not feasible to update millions of products' custom attributes separately and also custom attributes are category-specific. Is there any way to update the product attribute while updating the category attibute?

Comment: No , but if you create a category attribute only for product sku,,Write a code in layered navigation ,that when your multiselect value choose then get these product sku or id . I think it will help you .

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a product attribute
2. Create a Cron that should run and set the product attributes checking there category attribute values.
3. Use these product attributes to display layered navigation collection.